# Trying to concat values and group_by Postgres in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm trying to list all of my baseball players and their basic information in a view.  Most of the information is housed in a **Players** table.  However, I'm also trying to pull their position which is a column in another table called **Positions**.  The Players table doesn't have a direct association with this Positions table.  But, Players and Positions both have a has_many and belongs_to association with another table called **GameStats** that houses all of a players stats, including position played, for that game.  Here are my tables:

```
TABLES

Player Table

id | fname | lname
---+-------+-------
1  |  Joe  | Smith
2  |  Fred | Jones


GameStat Table

player_id | position_id
----------+-------------
    1     |     7
    1     |     7
    1     |     8
    1     |     8
    2     |     9
    2     |     9
    2     |     9
    2     |     9

Position Table

id | position
---+---------
 7 |   LF
 8 |   CF
 9 |   RF
```

I'm trying to join these three tables but I'm not getting exactly what I want.  Here is my query:

```
@position_players = BatterGameStat
  .select("player_id, players.fname || ' ' || players.lname AS name, players.bats AS bats, players.throws AS throws, position_id, array_agg(positions.position) AS pos")
  .group("batter_game_stats.player_id, batter_game_stats.position_id, fname, lname, bats, throws, position")
  .joins(:player, :position)
  .order(:lname)
```

Basically, I'm returning a list but if they play a different position in different games they are listed multiple times for each unique position with the following view code:

```
<% @position_players.each do |pp| %>
  <tr class="player">
    <td><%= link_to(pp.name, player_path(pp.player_id)) %></td>
      <td><%= pp.pos %></td>
      <td><%= pp.bats %></td>
      <td><%= pp.throws %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Here is what I want to get returned and what I am getting:

```
Desired returned html table:

   Player  |  Position(s)
-----------+-------------
Joe Smith  |  LF, CF
Fred Jones |  RF

This is what I'm actually getting:

   Player  |  Position(s) 
-----------+-------------
Joe Smith  |  LF
Joe Smith  |  CF
Fred Jones |  RF
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're abusing a `GROUP BY position` to produce a set of distinct `position`s for each person and that conflicts with your "GROUP BY for aggregation". Including `position` in the GROUP BY list is what breaks `('Joe Smith', array['LF'])` and `('Joe Smith', array['CF'])` into separate rows (i.e. separate groups).

You can throw a `distinct` into your `array_agg` and leave it out of your GROUP BY. The SQL you want looks like this:

```
select pl.id,
       pl.fname || ' ' || pl.lname as name,
       array_agg(distinct pos.position) 
from players pl
join game_stats gs on pl.id = gs.player_id
join positions pos on gs.position_id = pos.id
group by pl.id, pl.fname, pl.lname
order by pl.lname
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ac83e/3

The ActiveRecord version would look like:

```
@position_players = BatterGameStat
  .select("player_id, players.fname || ' ' || players.lname AS name, array_agg(distinct positions.position) AS pos")
  .group("player_id, fname, lname")
  .joins(:player, :position)
  .order(:lname)
```

I'd recommend that you be a little more explicit when formatting your array in the view as well:

```
<%= pp.pos.join(', ') %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looping through the position players, which is why your HTML table looks essentially the same as your `gamestats` table. I believe I have a solution that should help you. First of all, you should add a `has_many :through` association to your `Player` and `Position` models. I'll also add a `name` function to the `Player` model because you're generating it in your query, which you really shouldn't do.

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :game_stats
  has_many :positions, through: :game_stats, uniq: true

  def name
    self.fname + ' ' + self.lname
  end
end

class Position < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :game_stats
  has_many :players, through: game_stats
end
```

For more information about associations (which I'd suggest reading up on), see the [Rails Guide to Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html). With this change made, you can hugely simplify your query.

```
@players = Player.all
```

What you want are the players, not the join table. It's rare that you'll want to actually use this specific join model, since you don't have any additional columns in it. The last thing you can do is change your view as follows:

```
<% @players.find_each do |p| %>
  <tr class="player">
    <td><%= link_to(p.name, player_path(pp.player_id)) %></td>
    <td><%= p.positions.join(", ") %></td>
    <td><%= p.bats %></td>
    <td><%= p.throws %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

This should give you all you need to solve your problem. You should read through all the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/), because they'll help you out immensely. They certainly helped me when I was getting started.

Comment: (1) This will use a lot more queries to the database. (2) Won't `p.positions` yield four entries each instead of just the distinct ones as desired?

Comment: @muistooshort it will use more queries to the database, but it's so much cleaner and more explicit than that SQL query. And more queries isn't necessary worse if the one query is gigantic and slow (not that the one in the question is definitely slow). As for `p.positions` not being distinct, you're totally right. I updated my answer with `uniq: true` for `has_many :positions`

Comment: I'd disagree about "cleaner and more explicit", Rails people really need to stop speaking to the database using baby talk SQL (and no, that DHH doesn't understand database is no excuse). IMO of course.

Comment: @muistooshort Interesting. I guess I hadn't given that too much thought, because I haven't used rails on a large scale before. On a large scale, when performance matters, using explicit SQL is going to be much faster than convenient associations.

Comment: Thanks a ton **mu is too short** and **JKen13579**.  I learned a lot from both of your answers.